# discord emojis acting weird in code, numbers bundles of 3 ascii signs

Tags: python, unicode, discord

yeah. i was trying to make polls which automatically will have reactions below. normal thing i think. i saw similar question already but fix didnt worked (also didnt reacted). i want to put numbers or letters (:keycaps_one: , :keycaps_two: etc...). only that these default emojis are a bundle of 3 ascii characters, not as normal - one unicode character. (it is : keycaps, space, letter/number). as docs says - i can put in code: unicode codes, name OR just paste "ascii art" to code. so... how to put ascii art to code and make it work? non-working template below:

```py
@bot.command()
async def poll(ctx, *args):
    if ctx.channel.id == 853022130387812373:
        channel = bot.get_channel(853022915335028787)
        if len(args) == 0:
            await ctx.send("?! wat is dat ?!")
        elif len(args) == 1:
            await ctx.send("?! what ?! you didnt said answers !?")
        elif len(args) == 2:
            await ctx.send("ey, you didnt gave second option? how it can be a poll?")
        elif len(args) == 3:
            await channel.send(f"**QUESTION: {args[0]}** \n **answer 1:** {args[1]} \n **answer 2:** {args[2]}")
            await message.add_reaction("1️⃣")
            await message.add_reaction("2️⃣")
        elif len(args) == 4:
            await channel.send(f"**QUESTION: {args[0]}** \n **answer 1:** {args[1]} \n **answer 2:** {args[2]} \n **answer 3:** {args[3]}")
            await message.add_reaction("1️⃣")
            await message.add_reaction("2️⃣")
            await message.add_reaction("3️⃣")
        elif len(args) == 5:
            await channel.send(f"**QUESTION: {args[0]}** \n **answer 1:** {args[1]} \n **answer 2:** {args[3]} \n **answer 3:** {args[3]} \n **answer 4:** {args[4]}")
            await message.add_reaction("1️⃣")
            await message.add_reaction("2️⃣")
            await message.add_reaction("3️⃣")
            await message.add_reaction("4️⃣")
```

Comment: `"1️⃣ 2️⃣ 3️⃣ 4️⃣"` renders as  1️⃣ 2️⃣ 3️⃣ 4️⃣

Comment: I know but both these emojis and these new names doesnt work at me. Tested

Answer (score 0):

i already saw what bugged my code...
should be `message = await channel.send(xxx)` not `await channel.send(xxx)`